# Novel approach to the box counting calculation of fractal dimension

Tags: fractals

The box counting method of measuring the fractal dimension of an object is
$$D = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{ {\log N( \epsilon)} \over {\log { {1}\over{ \epsilon }}}},$$
where the classic example is calculating fractal dimension of the coast of England.

But let us imagine a scenario where the coast goes off to infinity in the north and south dimension. Let us fix $\epsilon$, and let $N$ be the independent variable, and let $R_N$ be radius of the smallest  circle that contains $N$ boxes. Can we not write

$$D = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}{{\log { R_N}}\over  {\log N}  }.$$

It seems to me this is a perfectly valid method, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: The box counting dimension is fundamentally only applicable to bounded sets.  Falconer discusses a notion of "modified box counting dimension" for unbounded sets.  I would check his texts for details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Upon further reflection, the definition you propose does not make any sense to me.  You fix some $\varepsilon$, but it is never used in the definition.  I also don't know what it means for $R_N$ to be the radius of the smallest ball which contains $N$ boxes---$N$ boxes which intersect the set?  are these boxes non-overlapping?  What do you mean by a "circle"?  Typically, "circle" just means the boundary of a disk.  Do you mean a disk?  or more generally, a ball (in $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

Comment: You may be right that my definition does not  make sense.   I have not tried to write it down rigorously.  It does make intuitive sense, but maybe there is a flaw in my intuition.  I'll try to find the time to work it out more rigorously.  Do you think it makes sense in 2D?

Comment: if the $N(\epsilon)$ (non-overlapping, on a grid) boxes of size $\epsilon$ are all in a straight line, $R_{N(\epsilon)}$ will be larger than when the boxes are clustered more compactly, which makes the size of $D$ counter-intuitive versus usual concept of dimension

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point.  You aren't taking into account that the boxes must efficiently cover the underlying fractal object.

Comment: If the fractal object is a straight line, then $R_N(\epsilon) = \epsilon N(\epsilon)$. if the fractal object fills in 2D (e.g. a Hilbert-like curve), then $R_N(\epsilon) = \sqrt{2} \epsilon \sqrt{N(\epsilon)}$.  In the first case, $D = 1$ as expected, but in the second case $D = \lim_{N(\epsilon) \to \infty} \frac{ \frac{1}{2} \log{2} + \log{\epsilon} + \frac{1}{2} \log{N(\epsilon)}}{\log{N(\epsilon)}} = \frac{1}{2}$ which is less.  Maybe taking the reciprocal of your $D$ would work, in this case giving the expected dimension $2$ ?

Comment: I probably should have written $R_N(\epsilon) \propto \epsilon N(\epsilon)$ and $R_N(\epsilon) \propto \epsilon \sqrt{N(\epsilon)}$, instead of equalities, but the end result is the same.

Comment: https://tglad.blogspot.com/2017/08/reframing-geometry-to-include-negative.html https://tglad.blogspot.com/2017/09/complex-dimensional-geometry.html

Comment: @Claude  If I require that the object extends to infinity in two directions, then doesn't that rule out a space filling object?  In my mind, I'm picturing a coast of England where the coast goes forever.